# Im deutschen Baurecht (oder Zivilrecht) was ist der Unterschied zwischen einer Grundschuld und einer Hypothek?

Tags: meaning

Warum gibt es, im Grunde genommen, nur eine Grundschuld, und keine richtige Hypothek wenn man sich ein Haus kauft?

Comment: Das ist leider eher eine juristische, als eine linguistische Frage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the German language.

Answer (score 4):

Die [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundschuld#Abgrenzung_zur_Hypothek) hat einen eigenen Absatz zur Abgrenzung von Hypothek und Grundschuld. Daraus sei zitiert:

> Im Unterschied zur Hypothek ist die Grundschuld abstrakt, genauer
>   nicht-akzessorisch. Das bedeutet, dass die im Grundbuch eingetragene
>   Grundschuldsumme unabhängig von der hiermit abgesicherten Kreditsumme
>   besteht. Beispiel: Der Kreditnehmer vereinbart mit dem Kreditgeber
>   einen so genannten Sicherungsvertrag, wonach die zu bestellende
>   Grundschuld über 150.000 € zur Sicherung eines Darlehens über 150.000
>   € dient. Benötigt der Kreditnehmer jedoch lediglich 140.000,00 €, so
>   hätte der Kreditgeber in einer Zwangsversteigerung das dingliche
>   Recht, 150.000 € als Versteigerungserlös zu verlangen. Diese
>   Diskrepanz entsteht auch bei späterer Tilgung, weil der Restkredit
>   immer geringer wird, aber der Grundschuldbetrag von 150.000 €
>   unverändert eingetragen ist.

Dort geht es etwa nochmal so lange weiter.